# setState not working with forloop in react function

Tags: reactjs

I am nesting two api calls inside componentDidMount, everything working fine, the only issue I have is the state do not update so I put some console logs to see what's going on

```
fetch reviews done!
analysis done!
false
analysis done!
false
analysis done!
false
```

As you can see the state of `loaded` never get updated  and by the way no data show up on the application, I probably messed up the logic with this function but I can't figure this out.

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(
      "https://url-one.com",
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "X-Spree-Token": "xxx"
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log('fetch reviews done!')
        this.setState(
          {
            list: responseJson.reviews,
          },
          () => {
            var obj = this.state.list;
            var data = [];
            for (let i in obj) {
              fetch(
                "https://url-two.com",
                {
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    api_key: "uuu",
                    data: obj[i].text
                  })
                }
              )
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(responseJson => {
                  data.push({'review': obj[i].text, 'analysis': responseJson.results * 100});
                });              
              this.setState({
                data: data,
                loaded: true,
                loading: false,
              });
              console.log('analysis done!')
              console.log(this.state.loaded)
            }
          }
        );
      });
  }
```

Of course if I use a separate function to update the state it works!

```
  show = () => {
    this.setState({ loaded: true });
  };
```

Comment: We are not recommended to do setState in loops in React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see the state of loaded never get updated

Because the `setState` happens asynchronous (not immediately update), using `console.log(this.state.loaded)` like that won't work as expected, instead, you might use the `setState` callback as you did with the second `fetch`, like so:

```js
this.setState(
  {
    data: data,
    loaded: true,
    loading: false
  },
  () => {
    console.log('analysis done!');
    console.log(this.state.loaded);
  }
);
```

---

### EDIT

I think we should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to make it work,  like this:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch('https://url-one.com', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'X-Spree-Token': 'xxx'
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log('fetch reviews done!');
        this.setState(
          {
            list: responseJson.reviews
          },
          () => {
            var obj = this.state.list;
            var data = [];
            var fetchArr = [];
            for (let i in obj) {
              let promise = fetch('https://url-two.com', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  api_key: 'uuu',
                  data: obj[i].text
                })
              }).then(response => response.json());

              fetchArr.push(promise);  // make an array of promises
            }

            Promise.all(fetchArr).then(values => {   //after all promises resolved, we'll receive an array of responseJson, we'll loop through it
              values.forEach((responseJson, i) => { //for each responseJson, we push it to the data array
                data.push({
                  review: obj[i].text,
                  analysis: responseJson.results * 100
                });
              });
              // finally, we update state
              this.setState(
                {
                  data: data,
                  loaded: true,
                  loading: false
                },
                () => {
                  console.log('analysis done!');
                  console.log(this.state.loaded);
                }
              );
            });
          }
        );
      });
  }
```

Comment: I understand what you did, it gonna work for sure but the goal here is to update the state not to console log

Comment: @blvckasvp I think I got it! We need to wait until 3 sub-fetchs finish before using `setState`, otherwise the `data=[]` is still an empty array.

Comment: the data list always get updated, the issue is if I put setState outside the forloop it execute before the forloop, even if the code is after obviously

Comment: @blvckasvp I updated the answer, the idea is that we'll use the `Promise.all()` to prepare our data before `setState`. The usage of `Promise.all()` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: well that's correct, I am able now to update the state and store analysis but since you added that promise I no longer have access to let i and btw only the whole object shows up, the issue is here data.push({ review:  obj[i].text,

Comment: Oh I see, the problem with the `index`,obj[i].text. I updated the answer, when using `Array.prototype.forEach()` we could use the second argument to access the index of the current element being processed in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple conflicting processes here that need to get shored up. You don't want to modify state during async actions because internally you will fire off a re-render, so I'd suggest reorganizing a bit. The loaded state is not resolving correctly because you aren't waiting for your subsequent requests to finish. Here is an example:

[image: Edit React and SCSS]

Comment: I like this approach but got Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): responseJson.forEach is not a function when trying to implement it. I'll keep you posted. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Note that I changed the response value because your example was not querying a public API. I bet it'd work for you if you switched it back to `responseJson.reviews.forEach(...` as needed.